# Which algorithm is faster for large values of n?

Tags: algorithms

Algorithm A running time satisfies the relation

$$A(n) = A \left(\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right) + n, A(1) = 2$$

and algorithm B running time can be expressed as

$$B(n) = 2B\left (\left\lfloor \frac n2 \right\rfloor\right) + \frac n2, B(1) = 1$$

Which algorithm is faster for large values of items
n? Justify your answer by finding (show all
solution steps) big-O notations for the running time of
$A(n)$ and $B(n)$.

I'm unsure how to apply big o notation to these relations? As its not trying to prove a function is less than another one. ie $f(x) < Cg(x)$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can understand asymptotic notation in a way similar to how you understand limits. How does the limit of $A(n)/B(n)$ behave as $n \to \infty$? If $B(n)$ is (eventually) strictly positive, then computing limits tells us everything we need to know:

- If the limit is $0$, then $A(n) = o(B(n))$
- If the limit is $\infty$, then $A(n) = \omega(B(n))$
- If the limit is a finite, positive number, then $A(n) = \Theta(B(n))$

If the limit doesn't exist, you can still glean information from the $\limsup$, if you know how to compute that.

(exercise: prove the above is true)

Answer (score 0):

Once you understand what [Hurkyl](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817129/65537) is saying about Big O notation **a hint specifially for solving recurrance relations stated in this way:** Have a look at the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form) and see if one of the three cases applies.

I am using this as an example for the second function $B$, because this represents the running time of the well known merge sort algorithm or something similar.

It is the [second case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2) because
$$ \frac{n}{2} \in \Theta(n^{\log_22}) = \Theta(n) $$
and thus
$$ B(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_22} \log n) = \Theta(n \log n)$$

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm able to use the master theorem as that has not been taught by my lecturer, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: If you substitute the definition of A(n) and B (n) back into the right hand side, it gets clear quite quickly.